# select from postgresql and insert if not exist in mysql golang

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, go

I have two different database servers, one is a mysql database server and the other is postgresql database server , both have a table called users  so I have to insert from the users postgresql table to the users mysql table and check if there is already something inserted (if not exist), how can I do one Database query with postgresql and mysql in the same time

//MYSQL CONNECTION

```
var err1 error
db, err1 = sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbusers?parseTime=true")
if err1 != nil {
    log.Fatal(err1)
}
```

//POSTGRESQL CONNECTION

```
psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+"password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD, DBNAME)
    db1, err2 = sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }
```

//Here is what i have tried

```
func GetUsersApiPostgres(c *gin.Context) {
var p Users
Users, err := p.GetUsers() //GetUsers will return all fields in users table
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
    "Users": Users,
})

}
func AddUsersApiMysql(c *gin.Context) {
firstName := c.Request.FormValue("firstname")
lastName := c.Request.FormValue("lastname")

p := Users{FirstName: firstName, LastName: lastName}

ra, err := p.AddUsers()//AddUsers will insert fields  defined in users table
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
msg := fmt.Sprintf("insert successful %d", ra)
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
    "msg": msg,
})
}
func (u *Users) GetMysqlUsersFromPostgresql{

}
```

I don't know how to use both function (Add & Get) in the last function

Comment: `Upsert` is what you're looking for: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/#using-insert-ignore

Comment: Thanks @JimJones but the problem is to work with both mysql and postgresql in one query  as you may notice for the code up  that i have two different database server

Comment: @Flimzy yes i tried you may check up i edited the post